# Angular, is it possible for DatePicker to show fewer years?

Tags: angular-material, mat-datepicker

Very similar to the example in the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples) `Datepicker with min & max validation`.

The Angular component shows extra years outside of the `minDate` and `maxDate`. In my use case, the valid `minDate` is 2018, and the component is still showing from `2000`. That is too much. In the documentation, I could not find the right parameters to set this UI setting.

[image: Angular view with too many years]

Just to be clear, what I want to achieve is the same view, but for example showing options only starting from 2016 instead of 2000. Is it possible?